# Azure After GetBlobReference Properties is empty

Tags: azure, properties, attributes

I try to get properties after or before download by BlobHelper.**GetBlobReference**() for loging  , at last I try with            blob.FetchAttributes(); but doestn work my properties are null. My container and my blob have not permissions

```
         public static CloudBlob GetBlobReference(string containerName,string fileName)
         {
        var blobClient = GetBlobClient();
        if (blobClient != null)
           {
            var contRef=blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            return contRef.GetBlobReference(fileName);
            }
        return null;
          }

         var blob = BlobHelper.GetBlobReference(SelectedContainer, 
         fileName);

        if (blob.Properties != null)
        {
          //I try to get Lenght of blob but it is -1
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the code for `BlobHelper.GetBlobReference`.

Comment: Fixed sir .. :) or did you mean for pic ?

Comment: If possible, please include code. Since `BlobHelper.GetBlobReference` is something you wrote, I don't know what SDK methods you used in there. By looking at that code, it will be easier for me to provide an answer. Thanks.

Comment: You have right I fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. `GetBlobReference` simply creates an instance of `CloudBlob` on the client and doesn't make a network request. From the documentation [`link`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblobreference.aspx):

> Call this method to return a reference to a blob of any type in this
>   container. **Note that this method does not make a request against Blob
>   storage.** You can return a reference to the blob whether or not it
>   exists yet.

If you want to get the properties populated, you must call [`FetchAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.fetchattributes.aspx) or use [`GetBlobReferenceFromServer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblobreferencefromserver.aspx).

Comment: I try fetchattribus after get reference doesnt work , I try now GetBlobReferenceFromServer will write the result.

Comment: Yep it is working :) I understand you the important thing is making a network request thank you for the info :)